# How to get new sentences by replacing each word one by one using python?

Tags: python

```
text_a = 'wordx'
sentence_1 = 'word1 word2 word3'
```

from this , trying create new sentences like

```
sentence_2 = 'wordx word2 word3'
sentence_3 = 'word1 wordx word3'
sentence_4 = 'word1 word2 wordx'
```

This is related to a nlp task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help you?

```py
text_a = 'wordx'
sentence_1 = 'word1 word2 word3'

sentences = []
split = sentence_1.split()
for i in range(len(split)):
    temp = split.copy()
    temp[i] = text_a
    sentences.append(" ".join(temp))

print(sentences)
```

It generates a list of sentences replaces by the certain `word_a`:
`['wordx word2 word3', 'word1 wordx word3', 'word1 word2 wordx']`

The only advantage it has that you create it dynamically, if the sentences are always the same you can create them manually like @Salem's solution.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to use string formatting :

```
text_a = 'wordx'
sentence_1 = f'{text_a} word2 word3'
sentence_2 = f'word1 {text_a} word3'
sentence_3 = f'word1 word2 {text_a}'
```

And this will give you the result you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
print(*[ sentence_1.replace(x, text_a) for x in sentence_1.split()], sep='\n')
```

or just to get a list, you could use:

```
sentences = [ sentence_1.replace(x, text_a) for x in sentence_1.split()]
```